# how to run java function from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a requirement in which I need to call some functions (which are defined in Java code) from Postgresql.

Please suggest what are the best approach to do. I am using `postgreSQL version 9.3`.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: You could try to get PL/Java to run with 9.3: https://blog.dbi-services.com/install-pljava-in-postgresql-9-5-1/ but be aware of the [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407308/330315)