# How to run a shell script in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to run a shell script in PostgreSQL and get output in a variable.

PostgreSQL Version - 9.3

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, you are right about Postgres 9.3. You can also answer for later database version. Actually, I want to run a java function from PostgresSQL, I have executed the code in a shell script. Now, trying to run shell script from PostgreSQL. In case this approach is wrong, please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a shell script inside the database, you'd have to install the [PL/sh](https://github.com/petere/plsh) procedural language.

I am not sure what you mean by a “variable” inside a database, but a function written in PL/sh can be used just like any other function.

Comment: I see, Strange requirement. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, My actual requirement to run a java function from PostgresSQL, I have executed the java code in a shell script. Now, trying to run shell script from PostgreSQL. In case this approach is wrong, please suggest. `Variable` is just a text variable defined in postgres function.

Comment: Yes, that approach is deeply wrong because it is overly complicated. If you *really* need to run Java code inside the database, you'd better use PL/Java.

Comment: Thanks let me check PL/Java. Can you please provide some useful links. You can also answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896456/how-to-run-java-function-from-postgresql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name has already provided that information there.